# NWjs window height changes when first dragged

Tags: nw.js

I'm dealing with nw.js recently and came across with a problem I couldn't figure out why. Problem like this: when i drag the app window the first time after i launch my app, the height changes(about 20px higher), and then it keeps the same.

Comment: PS: setting like this:"width": 500,
    "height": 340,
    "min_width": 500,
    "min_height": 340,
    "max_width": 500,
    "max_height": 340

Comment: What OS? What version of nwjs?